# Regex version of strip() - Ch. 7 Automate the Boring Stuff

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, regex, reinventing-the-wheel

Here is a practice exercise — [*Regex version of `strip()`*](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter7/) \$-\$

> *Write a function that takes a string and does the same thing as the
>   `strip()` string method. If no other arguments are passed other than the
>   string to strip, then whitespace characters will be removed from the
>   beginning and end of the string. Otherwise, the characters specified
>   in the second argument to the function will be removed from the
>   string.*

I have written the following code. Is there any better way to write it? Any feedback is highly appreciated.

```
import re

def regex_strip(s, chars = None):

    if chars == None:
        strip_left = re.compile(r'^\s*')
        strip_right = re.compile(r'\s*$')

        s = re.sub(strip_left, "", s)
        s = re.sub(strip_right, "", s)
    else:
        strip_left = re.compile(r'^[' + re.escape(chars) + r']*')
        strip_right = re.compile(r'[' + re.escape(chars) + r']*$')
        s = re.sub(strip_left, "", s)   
        s = re.sub(strip_right, "", s)
    return s
```

Here is an example output -

```
s = '.*    alphabetatheta   *4453   +-'
print(regex_strip(s, '.+-*'))

>>>    alphabetatheta      *4453
```

Comment: It all depends whether \s includes all the white space characters. There are tons of them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you call `regex_strip(s, "")`, you will get:

> re.error: unterminated character set at position 0

because neither `^[]` nor `[]$` is a valid regular expression.  You could avoid this by using `if not chars:` instead of `if chars == None:`.

---

There is no need to `re.compile()` your regular expressions; you aren't saving the compiled patterns anywhere for re-use.

---

You can simplify your logic by using the reg-ex to capture the middle, non-stripped portion of the string, instead of doing two replacements for the start and end trim operations:

```
import re

def regex_strip(s, chars = None):

    if chars:
        trim = '[' + re.escape(chars) + ']*'
    else:
        trim = r'\s*'

    return re.fullmatch(f"{trim}(.*?){trim}", s).group(1)
```

---

I'm not sure the point of asking you to write your own `strip()` function is to delegate the task to the reg-ex engine.  It seems like going out and buying a sledge hammer when the problem is to build a nut cracker.

Comment: Maybe something of value to some on the subject of regex: https://www.regular-expressions.info ; also the man page *`regex(7)`* (which is less detailed but still maybe of value; there is of course also *`regex(3)`* but that's for C).

Answer (score 8):

DRY. Both branches do identical `re.sub`s. Take them out:

```
if chars is None:
    strip_left = re.compile(r'^\s*')
    strip_right = re.compile(r'\s*$')
else:
    strip_left = re.compile(r'^[' + re.escape(chars) + r']*')
    strip_right = re.compile(r'[' + re.escape(chars) + r']*$')
s = re.sub(strip_left, "", s)   
s = re.sub(strip_right, "", s)
return s
```

I recommend to go one step further, and unify the computation of `strip_*`:

```
if chars is None:
    chars = string.whitespace

strip_left = re.compile(r'^[' + re.escape(chars) + r']*')
strip_right = re.compile(r'[' + re.escape(chars) + r']*$')
s = re.sub(strip_left, "", s)   
s = re.sub(strip_right, "", s)
return s
```

---

It is [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/what-is-the-difference-between-is-none-and-none) to compare against `None` as `chars is None` rather than using `==`.